# Using v-btn to change route only if some condition is met

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

How can i prevent this button from firing to the that url path??

I'm trying to make a method check based on some logic and then if it doesn't pass I need to prevent this button from doing anything.

Any help would be much appreciated:)

```html
<v-btn
  @click="checkIfCanCreateTO($event)"
  :to="{ name: 'New', params: { selected: selectedItems, readonly: false } }"
 >
  <v-icon small class="mr-2">mdi-account-plus</v-icon>
  Create New with
  {{ selectedItems.length }} item(s)
 </v-btn>
```

Comment: You probably wanna [disable](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#props-disabled) the button?

Comment: I don't want to disable it, I need to stop this event from happening

Comment: Which is what disabling the button usually does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the button to change route every time it is clicked but do it conditionally, do not use `to` prop!

Use only `@click` handler, check your conditions and then use `$router.push({ name: 'New', params: { selected: this.selectedItems, readonly: false } })` inside the handler...

Answer (score 0):

### Have you tried this?

```html
<v-btn
  @click.prevent="checkIfCanCreateTO($event)"
  :to="{ name: 'New', params: { selected: selectedItems, readonly: false } }"
 >
  <v-icon small class="mr-2">mdi-account-plus</v-icon>
  Create New with
  {{ selectedItems.length }} item(s)
</v-btn>
```

**Supplement to the answer**

You can add "[prevent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) events" to the function

```js
checkIfCanCreateTO(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // your code
}
```

Comment: yes, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Robertas In my answer, added new information, try again

Comment: I've tried this previously aswell, doesnt work..

Comment: @Robertas Then I can't figure out what your problem is. Can you form the expected result, and the actual one? And more data. You can update your question. Add your checkIfCanCreateTO function.

Comment: The expected result is that once I click the btn I make some checks in my methods, if checks fail, I prevent this button from redirecting me to `New` and just make an alert or smth that smth went wrong